# TypeScript import issue

Tags: typescript

i am writing a multi-file typescript web application. I have my core application code in a file called application.ts which I want to be called upon by my main (data-main) file is called applicationEntry. when I do declare module 'application' in my application.ts file everything works great. but when I try to add import statements in my application.ts file I get an error: "Invalid module name in augmentation, module 'application' cannot be found.", I am confused on why this error would be thrown when I simply add an import statement. I've searched around the net for some answer's but have found minimal amounts if not on that truly fix's my issue. Perhaps I am structuring my application wrong?  here is my script with the error:[image]

here is what it looks like in applicationEntry:[image]
EDIT:
basically what my problem is: it works fine if the file that is including doesn't import anything whereas if it does import something other modules suddenly cannot import the module. also i should note the import im trying to add is a typings definition file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code as below,

```
export module application
{
   export class Application
   {
      // Your code
   }
}
```

You need not declare the module.

Hope this helps!